# how can i overwrite css property in react-native

Tags: react-native

i have created custom button , `<View style={styles.buttonContainer}> <AppButton title="comes in" color="yellow" /> <AppButton title="register now" color="white"  /> </View>`when  i save my code both button giving me same color so where I created custombutton component I modify background color `return ( <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: colors[color] }]} > <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text> </TouchableHighlight> ); }`[image: this is working]
but problem is that like this I want to modify `marginVertical`  `export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = "" }) { return ( <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: colors[color] ,marginVertical=[marginVertical]}]} > <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text> </TouchableHighlight> ); }` and in welcome screen i called it like this`<View style={styles.buttonContainer}> <AppButton title="comes in" color="yellow" /> <AppButton title="register now" color="white" marginVertical="4"/> </View>`
[image]

Comment: try setting marginVertical variable with initial value 0 instead of empty string then pass a number to it eventually . and remove [] while using the variable in the style tag . Do it like this:
```<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: colors[color] ,marginVertical: marginVertical}]} >```

Comment: export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = "0" }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical: marginVertical },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

Comment: <AppButton title="register now" color="white" marginVertical="30" />

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: check below error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the marginVertical you can simply pass it like below rather than providing a key and using an array.

```
function AppButton({ title, color = '', marginVertical = 0 }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical:marginVertical },
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Also if you are planning on using multiple styles use a single style object and override it like below

```
function AppButton({ title, style={} }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        style,
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Comment: export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = "" }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
and i pass value in welcome screen
 <AppButton title="register now" color="white" marginVertical="30" />
 still getting error

Comment: try  <AppButton title="register now" color="white" marginVertical={30} />

Comment: export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = "0" }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

Comment: <AppButton title="register now" color="white" marginVertical={30} />

Comment: you are setting a string as the default value it should be  marginVertical = 0 not  marginVertical = '0'

Comment: { title, color = "", marginVertical = 0 }

Comment: export default function AppButton({ title, color = "", marginVertical = 0 }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[
        styles.button,
        { backgroundColor: colors[color], marginVertical },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
   <AppButton title="register now" color="white" marginVertical={30} />

Comment: @kokab updated my answer, copy it and try I dont see any error except for code formatting

Comment: check my answer

Comment: error while updating property 'marginVertical in shadow node of type:RCTVeiw
null
unknown value:0

Comment: In any of the instances of AppButton , do you use a string value for marginVertical ?

Comment: marginVertical: marginVertical  its working while adding this

Comment: You are welcome, I'll update the answer, but it worked for me dont know the reason though

Comment: i want to ask one thing more we are modifying so why we are not using array bcz to modify object we use array

Comment: You have already placed the styles inside an array so it will override, and you the styles.button would be overriden by the object you provided